# Java Interface Extension and Spring's Autowired

Tags: java, spring

I have this interface:

```
public interface RestService {
    //other methods
}
```

and this interface which extends `RestService`:

```
public interface NewRestService extends RestService{
        void downloadPOD(String baseUrl, String orderNo);   
}
```

My Implementation:

```
public class NewRestServiceImpl implements NewRestService { 
   public void downloadPOD(...);

   //other method implementations
}
```

When I do this, it says

> downloadPOD()is undefined:

```
@Autowired
private RestService restService;
...
restService.downloadPOD(...)
```

Please enlighten me. Thanks

Comment: As a note: Use constructor injection instead of using `@Autowired` on fields. (If you have just one constructor, you don't even need `@Autowired` on it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `downloadPOD` method is not defined in the `RestService` interface. If you're sure the right implementation will be injected, you can cast the bean:

```
@Autowired
private RestService restService;

((NewRestService) restService).downloadPOD(...)
```

Or if you need to use the api of the implementation, that is not in the interface, maybe it would be better to simply inject `NewRestService` or `NewRestServiceImpl`:

```
@Autowired
private NewRestService newRestService;
```

Comment: Thanks! I always thought it is good to use the highest level interface. BTW, is it a good idea to use casts? Are casts a source of runtime exceptions?

Comment: @Shazam yes, that's why it's better to autowire `NewRestService` as I stated below. No problem, if you like the answer, consider upvoting;>

Comment: @Shazam You should use the highest-level interface _that you can_. If you really need something more specific, then you need it. Lots of methods can take just a `Collection<T>`, but it only makes sense to `sort` a `List<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

downloadPOD() is defined in NewRestService not in REstService. Either declare downloadPOD() in RestService or autowire NewRestService. This is nothing to do with spring, it is java problem.